# IIS config or wifi config

Tags: iis, dns

I have a domain name "example - somedomain.com" AND i have a server i setup On my PC windows 10 running in IIS so if you would go to "example -  www.somedomain.com" you would get to my site. I have xfinity-comcast and if i would type [www.somedomain.com](http://www.somedomain.com) i would get an error but http://localhost works just fine i see my site. can anyone help me so when i type the .com name i see it on my PC... i see the site not using my wifi connections. Thank you

Comment: On IIS you can only define site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html To make proper requests, you need to configure DNS and forward the packets. It's purely a networking question so not covered here on Stack Overflow. If you are not familiar with DNS configuration, hire an experienced professional and that can save you from trying endlessly.

Comment: According to your description, more information is needed to analyze your problem, Can you post details about the error? and the configuration of your website in iis.

Comment: It's not really an error but a time out .. again I can go or anyone can go to my website IF not on my wifi connection but when I try on to go to the .com I get timed out because it can't be found? If I need to post the real site here let me know you'll see no issues thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.